# Error response from daemon: hcsshim::CreateComputeSystem: The virtual machine could not be started because a required feature is not installed

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I have downloaded Docker Desktop onto a Windows 10 Pro machine (1809). I am trying to do a `docker run hello-world` command, but I receive this error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: hcsshim::CreateComputeSystem 0e3c581b7316f66fd396f6007f3260ded7d934c5e6d53c9fedba279b9c0044c2:
        The virtual machine could not be started because a required feature is not installed.
(extra info: {"SystemType":"Container","Name":"0e3c581b7316f66fd396f6007f3260ded7d934c5e6d53c9fedba279b9c0044c2","Owner":"docker","IgnoreFlushesDuringBoot":true,"LayerFolderPath":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\0e3c581b7316f66fd396f6007f3260ded7d934c5e6d53c9fedba279b9c0044c2","Layers":[{"ID":"08298683-92e6-5d81-8efa-07df462bc835","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\da67c59750c9d72f917f4169d58fff3285b27d01c30c159f437b8ec8bace3fd3"},{"ID":"8ffbf2ed-0796-5433-969d-24c7c60eed76","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\20785c70b0b36964948ecf0180bbe644306ed1f70686864f3cf476229f3ae054"},{"ID":"d0522a69-fb9e-53ff-8eec-0492669a13de","Path":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\2c662c56ef3ffafe3f5cb6180ac24154c081866bb0a6c0e3c27fa5a3bcc957a7"}],"HostName":"0e3c581b7316","HvPartition":true,"EndpointList":["63F24577-D177-4DE9-8071-9325D00D5499"],"HvRuntime":{"ImagePath":"C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\2c662c56ef3ffafe3f5cb6180ac24154c081866bb0a6c0e3c27fa5a3bcc957a7\\UtilityVM"},"AllowUnqualifiedDNSQuery":true}).
```

Answer (score 17):

I had the same issue.
Run Windows Powershell as "Administrator" and run the following commands to enable containers and Hyper -V. Restart machine after executing the second command -

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName containers –All
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V –All
```

Comment: If running nested Hyper-V, remember to apply this on the host: Set-VMProcessor -VMName <VMName> -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true

Comment: I tried this, but still getting the error. I'm running in a Virtual Machine

Comment: For me this worked even without restarting the machine.

Comment: Outdated!, `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature : Feature name containers is unknown.`

Answer (score 2):

Enabling virtualization for BIOS fixed my issue.
See below url, or search google to enable virtualization in BIOS.
https://appuals.com/how-to-enable-vt-x-in-windows-10/

In Docker website it is mentioned that virtualization should be enabled as part of installation.

Answer (score 2):

May not really an answer for this question with the missing feature.  But I had a similar error-Message and found this:

When runing my `docker-compose up -d` I got

```
ERROR: for xyz_server  Cannot start service sql_server: 
           hcsshim::CreateComputeSystem 5828482....c5e4: 
           The requested resource is in use.
```

When commented out in the docker-compose.yml the line with
`mem_limit: 8192m` by adding  `#`

container is starting. Got idea from [dockerquestions](https://dockerquestions.com/2021/04/19/docker-for-windows-the-requested-resource-is-in-use-error-when-mem_limit-is-set/)

The resource in use was the memory.... May this will help someone.