# Using Gitlab-Runner for Windows on GitLab CI Pipeline with Docker Desktop

Tags: gitlab-ci, pipeline, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-for-windows, gitlab-runner

I would like to run my Gitlab-CI Pipeline in a Windows environment. Therefore, I use a Windows Gitlab-Runner which
uses Docker Desktop version 4.3.0 as executor.

The "Server", on which the Gitlab-Runner operates, has Windows 10 1809, build 17763.2300 and runner version 14.5.0.
When I tried to run the pipeline the following error occurred:

ERROR: Job failed (system failure): Error response from daemon: container b098e3522e8889f8a1ec6c48f40d84fb2eb2a398d2d0923a04fda47054b997e3 encountered an error during hcsshim::System::CreateProcess: failure in a Windows system call: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail:  Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000]
[Event Detail: onecore\vm\compute\management\orchestration\vmhostedcontainer\processmanagement.cpp(173)\vmcomputeagent.exe!00007FF6CC039F4B: (caller: 00007FF6CBFEE13A) Exception(6) tid(388) 80070002 The system cannot find the file specified.
CallContext:[\Bridge_ProcessMessage\VmHostedContainer_ExecuteProcess]
Provider: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000] (exec.go:66:14s)

[VIEW ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fy3YZ.png)

I tried to use a Windows Gitlab-Runner on a Client as well. It has a Windows 10 version 21H1, build 19043.1348
and runner version 14.5.1. The same error appeared again.

Both times I used a python image and a Windows image (mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:20H2).

It seems like the error occurs after the Cleanup but I don't understand the log error information.
The power shell already runs on admin privileges.

Does anyone know how this error can be solved?

Comment: What version of Docker Desktop are you running?

Comment: Hi I am running Docker Desktop version 4.3.0

Comment: It would be nice if you could copy + paste the text of the error messages into your question.  That way, search engines can index your problem and it will help other people with similar errors.  It also makes your question easier to read

Comment: hello @Inka.F, were you able to solve your issue here? If so, can you please provide an accepted answer or comment here pls of the details?

Answer (score 0):

The error message you posted indicates that the docker client itself needs to be launched with admin privileges.  You should try running Docker Desktop as an administrator.

[image: Run as administrator]

**Update**: Yes, from the new error message, it seems that you might need to enable the virtualization features in windows.

Here is a related question: [Error response from daemon: hcsshim::CreateComputeSystem: The virtual machine could not be started because a required feature is not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57431890/error-response-from-daemon-hcsshimcreatecomputesystem-the-virtual-machine-co)

You can enable them via running these commands in powershell (as administrator):

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName containers –All
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V –All
```

Also, check this blog post for other troubleshooting tips: https://keathmilligan.net/gitlab-docker-windows-visualstudio

According to the article, check your host and container version:

> A Windows container host can only run a container image that is of the same OS version or older. For example, if you are running Windows 10 or Server version 1909, you will not be able to run a version 2004 or newer image.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. An other error appeared. I changed the picture with the error message in the question. Do you have any advice on that as well?

Comment: @Inka.F I made an update regarding your new error message