# failed to start service utility VM (createreadwrite): hcsshim::CreateComputeSystem

Tags: docker, windows-server-2019

I want to run a Docker container in a windows server 2019 version 1809.
I have install docker and wehn building the image i get this error:

```
ending build context to Docker daemon  82.94kB
Step 1/18 : FROM ubuntu:18.04
 ---> c6ad7e71ba7d
Step 2/18 : RUN apt-get update   && apt-get -y upgrade   && apt-get -y install curl unzip git npm build-essential libsqlite3-dev zlib1g-dev
failed to start service utility VM (createreadwrite): hcsshim::CreateComputeSystem 0d5c1d1d04d1bfd001c47caf7179c3e79ac02e0a41557d3b14729d9bb2e33089_svm: The virtual machine could not be started because a required feature is not installed.
```

I have followed the instructions in:
to this [blog](https://bcthomas.com/2019/02/getting-started-with-linux-containers-on-windows-server-2019/)
and to solve the error i have found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59322463/15793842) and also this one for [linux containers in windows server](https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-run-docker-containers-on-windows-server-2019/)
but are not working and returning the same error.

docker info:

```
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  app: Docker App (Docker Inc., v0.9.1-beta3)
  cluster: Manage Mirantis Container Cloud clusters (Mirantis Inc., v1.9.0)
  registry: Manage Docker registries (Docker Inc., 0.1.0)

Server:
 Containers: 0
  Running: 0
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 0
 Images: 3
 Server Version: 20.10.9
 Storage Driver: windowsfilter (windows) lcow (linux)
  Windows:
  LCOW:
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: ics internal l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay private transparent
  Log: awslogs etwlogs fluentd gcplogs gelf json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Default Isolation: process
 Kernel Version: 10.0 17763 (17763.1.amd64fre.rs5_release.180914-1434)
 Operating System: Windows Server 2019 Datacenter Version 1809 (OS Build 17763.2686)
 OSType: windows
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 15.82GiB
 Name: name
 ID: alphanumeric serial
 Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: true
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

docker version:

```
Client: Mirantis Container Runtime
 Version:           20.10.9
 API version:       1.41
 Go version:        go1.16.12m2
 Git commit:        591094d
 Built:             12/21/2021 21:34:30
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default
 Experimental:      true

Server: Mirantis Container Runtime
 Engine:
  Version:          20.10.9
  API version:      1.41 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.16.12m2
  Git commit:       9b96ce992b
  Built:            12/21/2021 21:33:06
  OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
  Experimental:     true
```

UPDATE:

I have doen the steps in these two repos:
[linuxkit](https://github.com/linuxkit/lcow/releases)
also [stevedorus](https://github.com/slonopotamus/stevedore)

getting error `level=info msg="Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: image operating system \"linux\" cannot be used on this platform: operating system is not supported"`